# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, Pyinstaller searching for a directory \\_MEI97962\\cmudict\\VERSION

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to package my code as one exe using pyinstaller. I run this code to package it:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

I get my code as one exe file succefuly, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\user\documents\python\rhymer\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pronouncing\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\user\documents\python\rhymer\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "cmudict\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1156, in resource_string
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1401, in get_resource_string
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1540, in _get
  File "c:\users\user\documents\python\rhymer\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 341, in get_data
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI97962\\cmudict\\VERSION'
[13072] Failed to execute script main
```

The exe is trying to search for a folder named cmudict\VERSION but it can't find it.

Any advice?

EDIT*
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pronouncing

def open_file(fileLabel):
    """Open a file for editing."""
    global filepath
    filepath = askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")]
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    fileName = filepath.split('/')[-1][:-4]
    fileLabel.config(text=fileName + ' loaded')

def findRhyme(x):
    file = open(x, "r", encoding='UTF-8')
    word = wordEnrty.get()
    txt_edit.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    text = file.read().splitlines()
    text = [i for i in text if not i == '']
    text = [i for i in text if not i[0] == 'P' and not i[-1] == '"']
    Rhyme = [i for i in text if i.split()[-1] in pronouncing.rhymes(word)]
    Rhyme ='\n'.join(Rhyme)
    txt_edit.insert(tk.END, Rhyme)

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Rhymer")
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

txt_edit = tk.Text(window)
fr_buttons = tk.Frame(window, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=2)
fileLabel = tk.Label(fr_buttons, text="No file loaded")
wordEnrty = tk.Entry(fr_buttons)
btn_open = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Load Master File", command=lambda:open_file(fileLabel))
btn_rhyme = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Find Rhyme", command=lambda:findRhyme(filepath))

btn_open.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
wordEnrty.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
btn_rhyme.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)
fileLabel.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='e')
fr_buttons.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e'+'w')
txt_edit.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `with open(path, 'rb') as fp:` is this part of your code? is the `path` a valid location? navigate through and check if `C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI97962\\cmudict\\VERSION` exists too

Comment: @CoolCloud I just added a part of the code where I think it's causing the problem. That path does not exist. I don't know what it contains.

Comment: Your posted code should not be the cause of the error because there is no code involves opening file.  It just updates a label with the selected file from `askopenfilename()`.

Comment: @acw1668I just added the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, never debug `FileNotFoundError`s in `--onefile` mode. `--onefile` essentially a zip containing a `--onedir` build which unpacks it into a temporary directory at runtime. Because it's all temporary, it's generally impossible to if files are there because they get deleted as soon as your app closes.

You're issue is `cmudict` contains a file called `VERSION` which PyInstaller isn't collecting and is missing from your app.

**If you're using the `.spec` file** (just a Python script) this is easy to fix. Add:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
```

to the top of the spec then extend the `datas=[]` in the `a = Analysis(...)` to:

```
datas=collect_data_files('cmudict')
```

Then build using:

```
PyInstaller main.spec
```

**If you'd rather use the command line** then you need to tell PyInstaller about it using `--add-data=source:dest`. The `source` is the full file path to the `cmudict/VERSION` file inside your Python installation. And `dest` is just `cmudict/`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I followed the instructions, but still got an error:
pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI97962:cmudict/'
That's how I tried to make the call on command line:
`PyInstaller --add-data=C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI97962:cmudict/ main.spec`

Comment: No, you don't want to add the temporary dir because it doesn't exist until you run it. `source` should point to the original. Run `import cmudict; print(cmudict.__path__)` to locate your installation of `cmudict`.

Comment: My apologies for asking many time, but I am still getting errors. I ran `import cmudict; print(cmudict.__path__)` and got `['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python\\Rhymer\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\cmudict']` as the path. I am using the `--add-data` argument incorrectly. With the available info, what is the right way to make the full PyInstaller call in the command line. I am using Python 3.8.1.

Comment: `PyInstaller --add-data=C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Rhymer\venv\lib\site-packages\cmudict\VERSION:cmudict main.py`

Comment: Same error I recieved: `pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python\\Rhymer\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\cmudict\\VERSION:cmudict'`

Comment: Oops, you're on Windows. Use `;` instead of `:`.

`PyInstaller --add-data=C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Rhymer\venv\lib\site-packages\cmudict\VERSION;cmudict main.py`

Comment: I also see other data files in that package. You'd be much better off using the spec file.

Comment: Thank you very much. It finally worked and this answer gave more understanding of how to deal with Pyinstaller. I had some other errors after such as `ModuleNotFoundError`, but I was able to solve them by searching. Thank you again!